# How do I stop my image from stretching on larger screen sizes?

Tags: reactjs

I have a hero section that displays an image loaded from an API. It works fine on smaller screen sizes but stretches on bigger screens. How do I prevent this from happening and make sure that the image doesn't look stretched?

Apologies in advance if if my code is confusing, this was my first React project.
Thanks!

```js
  <div className="hero-section">
    <Slideshow movies={movies}/>
  </div>
```

```css
.hero-section {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```js
  <div className="slideshow">
      <div className="slideshowSlider"  style={{ transform: `translate3d(${-index * 100}%, 0, 0)` }}>
        {posters.map((poster, index) => (
          <img src={'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + poster} className="slide" key={index} style={{ poster }}/> 
        ))}
      </div>
```

```css
.slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100vw;
    background-color:  #222222;
  }

  .slideshowSlider {
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: ease 1000ms;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100vw;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  .slide {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `height: 50vh;` to `height: auto;` in `.slide` styles.

```
.slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100vw;
    background-color:  #222222;
  }

  .slideshowSlider {
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: ease 1000ms;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100vw;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  .slide {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto; // fixed!
    width: 100%;
  }
```